# Configuring pulseaudio for receive mode

Tags: networking, windows, pulseaudio

I am working on a project where I'll be running PulseAudio in receive mode on my raspberry pi.  As for the server side, we've been writing a custom application on windows that will send an RTP audio stream.

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding what PulseAudio needs in order to establish a connection to my custom program.

Basically i'm asking, what sort of functionality must we program for it to connect to the pulseaudio client on the rPi?  Can I just use an RTP stream or do I need to send an announcement packet?

Comment: is this of any help? http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index4h3

Comment: For more poratibility , use http://portaudio.com/ library.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I'm actually not concerned with the playback, but more so the network communication.  Can PortAudio stream RTP?

Comment: If this helps anybody else, basically I found that PA needs an SAP packet to listen to an RTP stream when setup with module-rtp-recv.  

I ditched this and went with just piping the data I got from using jrtplib straight into aplay